# On vector subspaces with multiple dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Just a very simple conceptual question - what does it mean for a span to be a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

For example, a homework problem of mine is as follows:

> Let $S = {x_1, ..., x_k}\in \mathbb{R^n}$. Check that $⟨S⟩$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Does this mean that for each $x = c_1x_1 + ... + c_kx_k, y = d_1x_1 + ... + d_kx_k\in ⟨S⟩$ we must have $x+y\in ⟨S⟩$, $\lambda x\in ⟨S⟩$, or does it mean for any such $x, y$ we must have $x+y\in \mathbb{R^n}$, $\lambda x\in \mathbb{R^n}$?

I would assume the second definition, but I'd like to be sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the first definition. Because you know that $\mathbb{R^n}$ is a vector space, the second thing you wrote is trivial.

To show that $W$ is a subspace of $V$, you have to show it is closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition, so you have to show that:

$\forall x,y \in W: x+y \in W$

$\forall x \in W, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}: \alpha x \in W$

or, equivalently:

$\forall x,y \in W,  \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}: \alpha x + \beta y \in W$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

However, I'm not sure I understand why they wouldn't just word the question, "Check that ⟨S⟩ is a vector subspace".

Comment: If an answer helped you, you can accept it so other users know your question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the second definition is not so useful as $\mathbb R^n$ is a vector space, so if you take any two vectors in a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ it is guaranteed that their sum will belong to $\mathbb R^n$ (analogously for any product by a scalar).

It would be useful to see what does the symbol $<\cdot>$ mean, with something instead of the dot. If I'm guessing correctly, $<\cdot>$ is the span of the elements of the set.

What does that mean? It means that, if $S=\{x_1,...,x_k\}$, $<S>$ is the span of those vectors. The span is defined as any vector $x$ that can be expressed as $x=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i x_i$, for some coefficients (unicity of the $a_i$ is not required).

From this definition, the proof that $<S>$ is avector space is trivial.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear - ⟨S⟩ is indeed the span of S.

It seems redundant to say that ⟨S⟩ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$...why would they not simply word the question "Show that ⟨S⟩ is a vector subspace"?

Comment: Ok, I thought you had a problem with definitions. Happy to see your doubt was solved in another answer.

Comment: The only definition that confused me was ⟨S⟩ being a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$. I'm still a little confused as to how that would be different than saying ⟨S⟩ is a vector subspace.

Comment: Well, when you say "vector subspace of $\mathbb R^n$", you're being more specific than saying "vector subspace". It's like saying "X is a subset of Y", instead of "X is a subset".

Comment: In this context, both things mean the same.

Comment: Ahh, that cleared it up. Thank you both! @Math_QED